# "I was waiting at the train station when the rain had stopped."

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

In the following sentence:

> I was waiting at the train station when the rain had stopped.

Is it correct to use the present continuous with the past perfect, or should I use the past simple?

> I was waiting at the train station when the rain stopped.

Comment: This is past continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is much more usual, and is the one to choose for most situations. There may be rare occasions where the first sentence would fit better in context, but I think you can safely forget those for now.

Comment: I think the first would have to be "I had been waiting at the station when the rain had stopped".